# Duda en C# Windows Forms

Tags: formularios, windows

c#

hay una propiedad que cuando tu maximizas la ventana lo que está dentro del cuadro se auto ajusta, y cuando la despliegas en propiedades sale como el cuadro rojo  donde tu seleccionas en que lugar quieres que se ajuste. 
no recuerdo el nombre

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Será esta? `Form.MaximizeBox`

Comment: Estuve mirando, pero nada. seguiré buscando, muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La propiedad en concreto es Dock, pero no es propia del form, sino de los controles.

Un saludo!

[image: Propiedad]

Comment: Excelente, eso estaba buscando, muchas gracias Rubén, agradecido!!!!

Comment: De anda compañero! Me alegra que te haya ayudado  :)